# How to check if the mouse moves, while the left mouse button is down, in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse

I need to find a way to check if the mouse moves in c#, while the left button is down.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an example (WPF):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(MainWindow_MouseMove);
}

void MainWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: 'The name 'MouseButtonState' does not exist in the current context' 
i get this error :/

Comment: You need to add a `using` at the top for its namespace.  The easiest way to do this in Visual Studio is to use its Add using feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3shw4wa2.aspx

Comment: What am i suposed to add there? I tried adding the namespace and i still get a bunch of errors, and the one that is there is 'method must have a return type'

Comment: My example showed what the code might be if your WPF control was named MainWindow.  From the error you showed, it's not, because `public MainWindow()` isn't recognized as a constructor.  Move the `this.MouseMove += ...` line to your control's constructor.